# Discreteness of Szpiro ratios among twist minimal curves?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

For an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$, let $D(E) = |\Delta_{\min}(E)|$ be the minimal (absolute) discriminant of $E$, that is, the smallest possible value of the discriminant running over all integral models of $E/\mathbb{Q}$, and let $N(E)$ be its conductor. Define the Szpiro ratio to be

$$\displaystyle \beta_E = \frac{\log D(E)}{\log N(E)}.$$

It is conjectured that for all $\varepsilon > 0$ one has $\beta_E < 6 + \varepsilon$ with finitely many exceptions. This is known as *Szpiro's conjecture*, known to be equivalent to the $abc$-conjecture.

It seems that most constructions of elliptic curves with large Szpiro ratio, approaching 6, comes from taking some fixed curve and taking twists; see for example this comment by Mike Bennet in a [previous question of mine](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416864/semi-stable-elliptic-curves-and-szpiro-ratios). Indeed, the suggestion is broader in the sense that for any real number $\alpha \in [1,6]$ and any $\delta > 0$ there ought to be an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$ whose Szpiro ratio satisfies $|\beta_E - \alpha| < \delta$.

If we restrict ourselves to *twist minimal curves* $\mathbf{E}^\min$, i.e., those curves $E/\mathbb{Q}$ which have the smallest discriminant among all curves $E^\prime/\mathbb{Q}$ isomorphic to $E$ over some algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ but not necessarily isomorphic to $E$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, then does it follow that the closure of the set

$$\displaystyle \{\beta_E : E \in \mathbf{E}^\min\}$$

is not equal to $[1,6]$?